# Programación BASH

Tags: bash

Buenas , estoy intentando crear un script el cual cuando lo ejecutes con dos parametros (Nombre y tamaño del fichero) te cree un fichero con esos dos parametros.

El caso es que quiero que si no se introduce un nombre se establezca un nombre predeterminado al fichero y lo mismo con el tamaño .

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Parametro1
#   $1

#Parametro2
### $2

fichero=$1
tamano=$2

    dd if=/dev/zero of=$1 count=1 bs=$2
```

Answer (score 4):

Bash, como todas las shell de tipo Bourne desde Unix V7, soporta una sustitución de parámetros de la siguiente forma:

```
${parametro-palabra}
```

Si el parámetro no está establecido, se devuelve *palabra* (después de realizar las expansiones correspondientes sobre *palabra*), en otro caso se devuelve el valor del parámetro.

Otra forma de sustitución, proveniente de Unix System III, es la siguiente:

```
${parametro:-palabra}
```

En este caso, un parámetro con un valor vacío, que es distinto de un parámetro no establecido, también se sustituye por *palabra*.

De esta forma, quedaría:

```
fichero="${1:-mificheropordefecto}"
tamano=${2:-4096}
```

Puedes obtener más información, en inglés, en:

- [La sección "Parameter Expansion" del manual de Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
- La especificación [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), en *Shell & Utilities*, *Shell Command Language*, *2.6.2 Parameter Expansion*.
- [La sección "Parameter Expansion" de la guía de Bash de lhunath](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).
- [En la página de Sven Mascheck sobre shells históricas](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Parametro1
#   $1

#Parametro2
### $2

if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]
then
    fichero=$1
    tamano=$2
else
    fichero='default_name'
    tamano=23
fi

    dd if=/dev/zero of=$fichero count=1 bs=$tamano
```

Puedes ir añadiendo condiciones para, por ejemplo, comprobar si te llega 1 parametro y es string o es entero entonces setear una variable y la otra ponerla por defecto... etc.. etc...